# How to track custom data on WebTrends Analytics

Tags: javascript, analytics, webtrends

I need to track custom events from WebTrends Analytics.

Right now I'm sending virtual page views like this

```
Webtrends.multiTrack({
    args: {
        "DCS.dcsuri": '/' + this.presentation  + '/' + slug,
        "WT.ti": title
    }
})
```

And this to track custom events (such as button clicks)

```
Webtrends.multiTrack({
    args: {
        "DCS.dcsuri": '/' + this.presentation  + '/' + slug,
        "WT.ti": featureName,
        "WT.dl": 99
    }   
})
```

First, I don't know if sending custom events like this is fine, but from their "API reference" I learned that by setting `WT.dl` to `99` basically means to track an event which doesn't already have a `WT.dl` value (so is custom).

Besides this I have to send custom data along with the other, like

```
"WT.user_name": userName,
"WT.user_position": userPosition
```

To complicate things further I do not have access to the WebTrends panels so my testing is limited to the Network tab of my browser's inspector.

Mozilla [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Engagement/Analytics/Webtrends/Tracking#Custom_Conversion_Events:_DCS_Tracking_Code) seems to be using another method, which is best explained [here](http://help.webtrends.com/en/analytics9admin/scenario_analysis_parameters.html), which confuses me further...

Also I just found out `DCSext.custom_param` which may be what I need, I just don't know how this will end up being included in the final custom report.